# I want to calculate sum of a column, but categorised by other column in R

Tags: r

I have a huge survey csv file, which I imported in Rstudio. Here is a sample data

```
User 1  User 2  Duration
5       2       7-11 months
5       5       Less than 1 month
5       5       4-6 months
5       5       4-6 months
5       4       4-6 months
5       5       2 years
4       6       1 year
4       4       4-6 months
4       8       7-11 months
4       4       2 years
3       3       Less than 1 month
3       3       7-11 months
3       3       1-3 months
```

I want to calculate sum of `user1`, filtering with duration, say `4-6 months`.

Till now I have used :

```
df %>% group_by(Duration) %>% summarise(count=n_distinct(User1)) %>% 
  +     filter(Duration=="4-6 months")
```

But its not returning proper values. Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: If you want the sume of user1, use `sum(User1)` instead of `n_distinct(User1)`. `n_distinct` will give you the number of distinct values, not the sum of values.

Comment: Also, please save the RStudio tag for problems with the code editor RStudio (for example, if your code ran fine in the terminal or RGui, but didn't work in RStudio).

Comment: And be careful about using the right name. The way your data is printed, it looks like the column name is `User 1`. In your paragraph, you use `user1`, and in your code block you use `User1`. These are all different. They all should be the same. Capitalization matters. Spaces matter (and spaces in column names complicate things - it's easier to avoid them).

Comment: It has few blank values as well, how should avoid that in this code?

Comment: It is returning NA

Comment: Have a look at `?sum`, you can set a parameter to remove `NA` values.

Comment: now it returns 4-6 months  NA  TRUE, I used na.rm=TRUE just after the Sum function.

Comment: Use `na.rm = TRUE` *in* the `sum` function, not after it.

Comment: df %>% group_by(Duration) %>% summarise(count=sum(User1), na.rm = TRUE) %>% filter(Duration.=="4-6 months") This is the code I used.

Comment: Got it, thank you, I used it inside now :)

Answer (score 1):

Your column name may be incorrect:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Duration) %>%
 summarise(sum_user1 = sum(`User 1`, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
 filter(Duration=="4-6 months")
```

Comment: edited to reflect correct column name, and removed ungroup() - thanks.

Comment: Okay, edited again.  Thanks.